# I create a todo list system and I use a map to make a loop for all the items I have. But items are stuck for me in the same row in the table

Tags: reactjs

I create a todo list system and I use a map to make a loop for all the items I have.
But items are stuck for me in the same row in the table.
This is a system I used to build in js vanila and now for practice I run it in react.

I would be happy for a solution.
In js vanila I would use insertAdjacentHTML
But I'm looking for the solution in react

**demo** for the app: https://v1-todolist.netlify.app

**My Problem** [All items in one row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo1wv.png)

I need not all items to be on the same line I need it to be dropped line like here
[Example of how the item should look properly.
This system I built it in js vanila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDvxD.png)

if i add Div it not work
[It does not sit well in the table and I also get a validateDOMNesting (...) error:  cannot appear as a child of .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3GF.png)

my code **App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./Form";
import Alert from "./Alert";

function App() {
  const [nameTask, setNameTask] = useState("");
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState("Low");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({ show: false, type: "", msg: "" });

  const handlerSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!nameTask) return showAlert(true, "danger", "you cannot input empty");
    const newList = {
      id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
      title: nameTask,
      priority: priority,
    };
    setList([...list, newList]);
  };

  const showAlert = function (show = false, type, msg) {
    setAlert({ show, type, msg });
  };

  return (
    <article className="vh-100 gradient-custom-2">
      {alert.show && <Alert {...alert} showAlert={showAlert} />}
      <Form
        list={list}
        setNameTask={setNameTask}
        setPriority={setPriority}
        handlerSubmit={handlerSubmit}
      />
    </article>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Form = function ({ handlerSubmit, setNameTask, setPriority, list }) {
  return (
    <div className="container py-5 h-100">
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div className="col-md-12 col-xl-10">
          <div className="card mask-custom">
            <div className="card-body p-4 text-white">
              <div className="text-center pt-3 pb-2">
                <img
                  src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-todo-list/check1.png"
                  alt="Check"
                  width="60"
                />
                <h2 className="my-4">Task List</h2>
              </div>

              <form className="form-task" onSubmit={(e) => handlerSubmit(e)}>
                <div className="col-auto">
                  <input
                    name="name-task"
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control task-input"
                    id="autoSizingInput"
                    placeholder="Add Task"
                    onChange={(e) => setNameTask(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Default select example"
                  onChange={(e) => setPriority(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value="Low">Low</option>
                  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                  <option value="High">High</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                  submit
                </button>
              </form>
              <table className="table text-white mb-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Task</th>
                    <th scope="col">Priority</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr className="fw-normal">
                    {list.map((item, index) => {
                      return (
                        <React.Fragment key={index}>
                          <th>
                            <span className="ms-2" data-name={`${item.title}`}>
                              {item.title}
                            </span>
                          </th>
                          <td className="align-middle priority-class">
                            <span className="badge ${value.color}">
                              {item.priority}
                            </span>
                          </td>
                          <td className="align-middle">
                            <h6 className="mb-0" data-id="${value.id}">
                              <a className="remove-link" href="#">
                                <span className="badge bg-gradient remove">
                                  ❌
                                </span>
                              </a>
                              <a className="complete-link" href="#">
                                <span className="badge bg-gradient complete">
                                  ✔
                                </span>
                              </a>
                            </h6>
                          </td>
                        </React.Fragment>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-benji-se394n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I was able to solve your issu just by adding a flex propriety to the panel that contain your list and by changing `React.fragment` by a `div`.

However it would perhaps be better to swap the node with the class `fw-normal` to a `div` and change the `React.fragment` to the node `tr`.

Comment: I get an error and it also does not fit well in the table.
I edited the post for you to see

Comment: Yes of course.
Same error.
And the same problem that it does not sit well on the table
you can see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3GF.png

Comment: Yeah my bad tr and div cannot be child of each other. And if you try this : https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-benji-se394n?from-embed=&file=/src/Form.js

Comment: I get the same code.
And the same error of course

Comment: I changed the code between my last comment and my first answer. I just placed the ```list.map``` in the ```Tbody ``` and the ```map ``` return only ```tr``` node

Comment: tnx you help me a lot :)